# Javascript : how to reduce the memory size of a number?

Tags: javascript, memory, types, numbers, size

Does anyone know how to reduce the memory size of a number in JavasScript, if i know in advance that my number is between 0 and 100 ?

Example and explanation of my problem :

My JavaScript application works with very big objects : thousands of children for each one.
My objects look like collections of "sims" :

```
[
  {
    gender : "male",
    age : 45
  },
  {
    gender : "female",
    age : 21
  },
  {
    gender : "female",
    age : 78
  },
]
```

- The memory size of a string like "female" is 12 bytes (female.length*2)
- The memory size of a number indicating "female" would be 8 bytes
- The memory size of a boolean indicating "female" would be 4 bytes

Great ! I can reduce the memory size of my objects, using booleans !

But do you know a way to reduce the memory size of the "age" property ?

Each one takes 8 bytes, although i know the number can't be 152042456.985, but only > 0 and < 100.

An idea ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can use [Int8Array](http://www.javascripture.com/Int8Array) but there's basically no point. JavaScript is just the wrong language for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer needed to store the "link" will add 4-8 bytes to every storage mechanism that uses a string or any kind of an object for the age. Numbers are the most space-efficient you can get, typed arrays notwithstanding.

Comment: Does anyone know where to find the official/real memory cost of all data types and pointers in JavaScript ?

Comment: That depends a lot on the internals of the implementation and it's hard to find documentation about it. V8 for example seems to use 4 bytes for small integers, and store everything else on heap, adding 4 bytes of storage for the pointer to whatever is already needed (assuming I understand this correctly): http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/objects.h

Answer (score 1):

You could store ⌊32 ÷ 7⌋ = 4 ages in one integer easily enough; you could also use GZip compression, or arithmetic encoding, or all number of fancy tricks.

But why bother? There's no way this is actually a problem for you right now. The memory overhead of an object itself is probably more important. 32 bits is fine, and "thousands of children" is not really a significant number. 999,999 ages (the highest "thousands") is about 3MB of memory.

(You're saying, by the way, that a number representing "female" would be 8 bytes, but integers are stored internally as 4 bytes by all common JavaScript engines.)

Comment: 4 bytes to store an integer, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Joni: Not at the moment (I see it all the time but can't pinpoint where) but will [this](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=973) do? Or the ECMAScript spec for bitwise operations, which implies it a little (they cast to 32-bit integer)? Sorry :)

Comment: I found this: http://wingolog.org/archives/2011/05/18/value-representation-in-javascript-implementations Interesting stuff...